# c++ trouble reading in an array to a struct

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am reading in data to a struct array. the data is separated by possible blank lines which i must ignore. my code is not working im wondering why

```
struct Location
{
string state;
string city;
int zipcode;
}
```

and heres the reading in im getting trouble with.

```
while (!fin.eof() && size < 50)
{
getline (fin, location[size].state);
getline (fin, location[size].city);
fin >> location[size].zipcode;

if (location[size].empty()) //to ignore blank lines but its not working?
continue;
size++;
    }
```

any ideas? could it be the  compiler?

Comment: No, it's never the compiler. (At least not as long as you're asking on SO.)

Comment: can you add the contents of hte input file and the error you get..?

Comment: Is that real code? `Location::empty()` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: location.empty() isn't even defined in your `struct Location` - what is actually the problem?  Does this even compile?

Comment: and I don't know what your empty function does, but remember "blank" lines aren't necessarily black - there could be all sorts of whitespace, etc. so I hope they are taken care of

Comment: right im not trying to call empty from the struct but the syntax looks as so from what i studied on structs and empty, they both use the "."  which is confusing

Comment: Not as confusing as your inconsistent use of "." (to say nothing of other punctuation and grammar). Take the number of people you want to look at your problem, multiply by the amount of effort you want each reader to expend on your behalf, and expend at least that much on making your text easy to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to check for an empty string but are unintentionally trying to call `empty()` on a `Location`.

Did you mean

```
if (location[size].state.empty() && location[size].city.empty())
    continue;
```

**Edit:**
If you would like for your code example to work as is and you are able to modify `struct Loaction` you could do the following.

```
struct Location
{
    std::string state;
    std::string city;
    int zipcode; //who cares about zip+4

    Location():zipcode(0){};
    bool empty()
    {
        return state.empty() && city.empty() && !zipcode;
    }
};
```

Comment: ah this is more of  what im attempting but its telling me "method empty could not be resoled"

Comment: That is because you are trying to call empty on a Location which does not define it. If you like an empty method for Location see my edit.